# Check if $REPLY is in a range of numbers

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

I'm writing a shell script for Linux, using Bash, to translate any video-file into a MP4. For that, I'm using `avconv` with `libvorbis` for audio.

Inside my script, I have a question for the user :

```
read -p "- Audio Quality [scale from -2 to 10] ? "
    if [ -n "$REPLY" ] ; then
    ABITRATE="-aq $REPLY"
    fi
```

My "ABITRATE" string goes into the final `avconv` command-line.

But I would like to give the user the opportunity to answer that question with a value in Kb (Kilobit), and translate it into the scale that `libvorbis` uses.
The "scale from -2 to 10" is this :

```
Quality Kbit/s  Normalization
-----------------------------
 -2      ~32        y
 -1      ~48        y
  0      ~64        y
  1      ~80        y
  2      ~96        y
  3     ~112        y
  4     ~128        n
  5     ~160        n
  6     ~192        n
  7     ~224        n
  8     ~256        n
  9     ~320        n
 10     ~500        n
```

I would like to know how to check if my $REPLY is in a range of number. For example, I would like my script to do something like this :

```
if [ $REPLY is a number between 1 and 32 ] ; then 
 REPLY="-2"
elif [ $REPLY is a number between 33 and 48 ] ; then 
 REPLY="-1"
fi
```

Is this possible (I'm willing to say 'yes of course, shouldn't be hard' but I don't know the syntax to use) ?

Comment: AFAIK, Vorbis isn't a valid audio codec in an MP4 file (you want to use AAC or possibly MP3)...

Comment: Thank you, it worked well on VLC but Totem doesn't want to read it. I'm switching to libvo_aacenc

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `[` command/shell builtin has comparison tests, so you can just do

```
if [ "$REPLY" -ge 1 ] && [ "$REPLY" -le 32 ]; then REPLY=-2;
elif [ "$REPLY" -ge 33 ] && [ "$REPLY" -le 48 ]; then REPLY=-1; fi
```

where `-ge` means greater-or-equal-to (and so on). The `[` command is just a command, not special syntax (it's actually the same as `test`: check out `man test`), so it NEEDS the space after it. If you write `[$REPLY` it will try to find a command named `[$REPLY` and execute it, which won't work. The same goes for closing `]`.

Here, we're using the `&&` shell operator to run the second command only if the first is successful. `[` also supports `-a` to *and* two tests, but it's deprecated and its usage should be discouraged as it causes arguments not to be parseable reliably.

Edit: to test if the number is integer (if that can happen in your code), first do the test

```
if [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
   existing code
else echo "$REPLY is not an integer" >&2 && exit 1; fi
```

Of course all these bracket expressions return 0 (true) or 1 (false) and can be combined. Not only you can put everything in the same bracket, you can also do

```
if [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$REPLY" -ge 1 ] && [ "$REPLY" -le 32 ]; then ...
```

or something similar.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you ! Could I use instead simple comparison expression like `>=` ?

Comment: Bash allows many types of brackets for testing. You have these traditional `[` brackets, which work as seen in `man test`. These are traditional and fool-proof. Then, you have a lot of bash builtins. You have `[[` which are similar, but not exactly the same, as this one doesn't expand pathnames (there, < = > mean string comparisons, and integer comparisons are the same as in `[`). Both also have a lot of tests for file existence, permissions and so on. Then you have single `(` and double `((` used in @devnull's answer. Check out `man bash` under `Compound Commands`.

Comment: @MrVaykadji I highly recommend you also test whether the variable is a number, you might get unexpected results otherwise: `foo='a'; [[ "$foo" -lt 32 ]] && echo yes`

Answer (score 15):

You could simply say:

```
((REPLY>=1 && REPLY<=32)) && REPLY=-2
((REPLY>=33 && REPLY<=48)) && REPLY=-1
```

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> `((...))`
>
> ```
> (( expression ))
> ```
>
> The arithmetic expression is evaluated according to the rules described below (see [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic)). If the value of the expression
>   is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.
>   This is exactly equivalent to
>
> ```
> let "expression"
> ```

Comment: I like the simplicity, but what are the `((` ? I tried to use them in prompt and it seems to work like `if [  ] ; then` but I didn't knew that existed.

Comment: @MrVaykadji Added a reference from the manual.  Let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: @MrVaykadji Moreover, saying `if [ condition ]; then foo; fi` is equivalent to saying `condition && foo`.

Comment: Okay, nice ! I would like to accept both your aswers (Orion and you) if I could. Thanks a lot for all this, I learned a lot.

Comment: You may want to strip leading zeros if you use this. `a=08; (( a > 1 ))` will error since 08 is considered octal. you could also force decimal with `10#$REPLY`. `cmd && cmd` isn't quite the same as `if cmd; then ...` Once you need a `else` part, chaining logical `&&` and `||` can cause subtle bugs.

Comment: @MrVaykadji It's good to have multiple answers to a question.  You'll often find that those provide different perspectives to solving a problem.  Good that you learnt something from the various answers that you got.

Comment: @llua In cases as simple, short-circuiting is pretty much equivalent.  Thanks for the tip about numbers with leading zeros being treated as octal; that would happen in pretty much every language!

Comment: Oh, I was thinking, should it be `((REPLY>=1))` or `(($REPLY>=1))` ?

Comment: @MrVaykadji You don't need the `$` in the arithmetic context.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p "- Audio Quality [scale from -2 to 10] ? "
if [ -n "$REPLY" ] ; then
    ABITRATE="-aq $REPLY"
fi

echo "You chose : $ABITRATE : $REPLY"
## If 0 < $REPLY < 33 and $REPLY is a number
if [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$REPLY" -gt 0 && "$REPLY" -lt 33 ]]
then
    echo "GOOD"
else
    echo "BAD"
fi
```

Comment: The regular expression must not be quoted, otherwise it's treated as literal string. You're also only matching single digit numbers. It should be `[[ ... && "$REPLY" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]`, I think?

Comment: @ByteCommander eeeek! You're absolutely right, thanks.

Comment: You'd want to do the `[[ $REPLY =~ ...]]` first. In bash, the `[[ x -gt y ]]` as opposed to `[ x -gt y ]` interprets x and y as arithmetic expressions, so it's important to sanitize first as otherwise you have a command injection vulnerability. Try for instance `a='a[$(uname>&2)0]' bash -c '[[ $a -gt 0 ]]'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, test whether the input is numeric. For example, using the regular expression match operator of [bash conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b):

```
if [[ $REPLY =~ -?[0-9]+ ]]; then
  echo "Invalid input (not numeric): $REPLY"
  exit 2
fi
```

To test numeric ranges, you have two possibilities:

- the `-gt` operator of [conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) inside `[ … ]` or `[[ … ]]` (beware that the `<` and `>` operators do string comparison, not numeric value comparison, so `[[ 10 < 9 ]]` is true);
- the usual [arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) operators inside `((…))`.

Thus:

```
if ((REPLY >= -2 && REPLY <= 10)); then
  : # do nothing -- pass directly to libvorbis
elif ((REPLY <= 24)); then
  echo "Value outside supported range: $REPLY"
  exit 2
elif ((REPLY <= 135)); then
  REPLY=$(((REPLY+8) / 16 - 4))
elif ((REPLY <= 271)); then
  REPLY=$(((REPLY+16) / 32))
elif ((REPLY <= 400)); then
  REPLY=9
elif ((REPLY <= 707)); then
  REPLY=10
else
  echo "Value outside supported range: $REPLY"
  exit 2
fi
```

(You may want to use different approximation rules, I don't know if the ones I chose are the best here.)

Answer (score 1):

To correctly detect if an string is a (decimal) number we first need to define what is a decimal integer number. A simple and yet quite complete definition is:

> A sequence of an optional sign (+ or -) followed by no more than 18 (significant) decimal digits.

And this steps are needed:

1. Remove all characters that are not decimal digits (after the sign).
2. Remove the all the optional leading zeros. Leading zeros will cause the shell to believe that the number is in octal.
3. Limit the max size of the integer to 18 digits. Below 2**63-1 (max 64 bit integer).

Just one regex will do most of that:

```
re='^([+-])?0*([0-9]{1,18})$'
[[ $number =~ $re ]] && integer=${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}
```

The code to process several numbers is:

```
#!/bin/bash
DebugLevel=4     # 1:fatal 2:error 3:warn 4:info 5:debug 6:trace

SayMsg    (){   local a; a=$1; shift ;            # Log level
                [[ $a -le $DebugLevel ]] && printf '%s' "$@" $'\n' >&2 ;
            }
SayError  (){   a=$1; shift; printf '%s' "$@" $'\n' >&2; exit   "$a";   }

parseint  (){   local re # Parse the first argument as an integer or fail
                re='^([+-])?0*([0-9]{1,18})$'
                [[ $1 =~ $re ]] || { SayMsg 4 "Invalid number $1"; return 2; }
                integer=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
                echo "integer=$integer"
             }

while read val; do
    parseint "$val"
    done <<-\_EOT_
    0
    1
    10
    100
    2345
    123456789012345678
    923456789012345678
    999999999999999999
    0000000012345
    +023
    -00045
    -76
    ""
    ''
    a
    abc
    1234567890123456789
    7.23
    -8.17
    1e3
    10+11
    _EOT_
```

Which will print:

```
integer=0
integer=1
integer=10
integer=100
integer=2345
integer=123456789012345678
integer=923456789012345678
integer=999999999999999999
integer=12345
integer=+23
integer=-45
integer=-76
Invalid number ""
Invalid number ''
Invalid number 
Invalid number a
Invalid number abc
Invalid number 1234567890123456789
Invalid number 7.23
Invalid number -8.17
Invalid number 1e3
Invalid number 10+11
```

Once that the number is clean and clear, the only missing test is to limit the range of values. This simple couple of lines will do that:

```
(( 1  <= integer && integer <= 32 )) && REPLY="-2"
(( 33 <= integer && integer <= 48 )) && REPLY="-1"
```