# Can I put ranges to parameters?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this code:

```
if [[ $1 = "-s" ]] && [[ $2 = 0-9 ]]
then
  echo "yes"
fi
```

0-9 does not work for me. 
What I really want is to type, for example, -x 3 (or any number).

Comment: [Check if $REPLY is in a range of numbers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118856)

Answer (score 8):

```
if [[ $1 = "-s" ]] && [[ $2 -ge 0 ]] && [[ $2 -le 9 ]]
```

> `-ge`: greater-than-or-equal
>
> `-le`: less-than-or-equal

Answer (score 6):

This is possible, but you need to use a character class (`[0-9]`).For example:

```
if [[ "$1" = "-s" ]] && [[ "$2" = [0-9] ]]
then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

However, the above is only true of `$2` consists of a single digit. If you want `$2` to consist of one or more digits, use:

```
if [[ "$1" = "-s" ]] && [[ "$2" != *[!0-9]* && "$2" = [1-9]* ]]
then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

In newer bash versions, you can also use regular expressions:

```
if [[ "$1" = "-s" ]] && [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

The `^` matches the start of the string, and `$` the end. The `+` means "0 or more". So, `^[0-9]*$` will only be true of the string consists of nothing but one or more digits from the beginning until its end.

Comment: You don't need the regex match operator to test if a variable consists of a single digit: `[[ "$1" = "-s" && "$2" = [0-9] ]]`. You don't need the regex match operator to test if a variable consists solely of digits: `[[ "$1" = "-s" && "$2" != *[!0-9]* && "$2" = [1-9]* ]]` (here I also reject leading zeros and empty strings).

Comment: Why are you breaking out the regexes for integer comparisons?

Comment: @BlacklightShining for no good reason. Simply because that was the first approach that occurred to me and because I _like_ regexes. Still, fair enough, answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ "${#1}${1#-s}" = "$((${2%%*[!0-9]*}0?2:-1))" ] &&
echo yes
```

...if you balance the comparison you can sometimes shorten the test.

I prefer `case` though:

```
case ${1#-s}:$2 in
(*:*[!0-9]*|*:) ;;
("${1:+:$2}")   echo yes.
esac
```

Basically the idea is to rule out *any* match for a non-digit. For example:

```
[ "${2:+1$2}" = "1${2##*[!0-9]*}" ] && 
echo '"$2"' contains at least one character which \
         is a digit and zero which are not digits.
```

It's much more simple with `case` because you have multiple branches.

```
case $1:$2 in
(*:*?"$2")
    echo '"$1"' contains a "':'";;
(*:*[!0-9]*|*:0*[89]*|*:)
    echo '"$2"' either contains a not-digit character, no characters, \
           or is an invalid octal constant - or perhaps a mix-and-match;;
([!-]*|?[!s]*|??[!:]*)
    echo '"$1"' is either empty, doesn\'t match '-s' in its first two characters, \
          or is more than two characters. Or perhaps a mix-and-match.;;
(*) echo there are no more possibilities other than the one you want.
    echo but you can get here a lot sooner, as demonstrated above.
esac
```